# Labels are not appearing on my iPad Mini - Swift SpriteKit

Tags: iphone, ipad, swift

As the title states - Labels appear fine on my iPad Air - iPhone 4 - iPhone 5 - iPhone 6+ but when i test it on my iPad Mini some Labels don't show, but it is only upon the first initial presentation of the scene - After i come off the scene and then open it up again all the labels will come back (well most of them) takes a couple of attempts to get all the labels to show. But it is only on the iPad Mini

```
    var powerLabel = SKLabelNode()
    powerLabel.text = "Power-Ups: On"
    powerLabel.fontSize = 26
    powerLabel.position = CGPointMake(width, CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame) - 240)
    self.addChild(powerLabel)
```

This is one of the labels which doesn't show - If i come away from the scene and then navigate back to it, it will load. But on the first take it doesn't load

Comment: What kind of labels? SKLabelNodes? Can we see the code?

Comment: Sorry pal was busy all day - They are SKLabelNodes il will update the code now

Comment: Well the issue is probably with the position. Is it in landscape mode? I think that might be known to throw off the coordinate system. Try placing the label in the center of the screen and see what happens.

Comment: Good thinking! Just tried that and it does the same thing. However, i have deduced that it is the zPosition. Setting the zPosition of the SKLabelNode to 100 will show the label all the time. I guess i will just have to add the zPosition to every label :(

Comment: Well that just means there is something with a higher z position covering it. Try printing the z positions of every child node in the scene and see what might be blocking it. However, just giving it a very high z position value works as well.